# send mail Php Proplem

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

i am having an issue with PHP Mailer. It is sending a only Title of label without the content insert on each label the mail view as this :

Name :

Email:

Subject:

Message:

i do not have any information about php as a code , any help

Html code

```html
<section id="contact-page">
<div class="container">
<div class="center">
<h2>Drop Your Message</h2>
</div>
<div class="row contact-wrap">
<div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Name *</label>
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Email *</label>
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Phone</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Company Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Subject *</label>
<input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Message *</label>
<textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btnbtn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Submit Message</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

```
php code 
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you '
);

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = myemail@email.com';
$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;
$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');
```

echojson_encode($status);
die;

Comment: Why are you using stripslashes? To prevent injections?

Answer (score 0):

**if you are sending mail from localhost. you will be some changes in php.ini and sendmail file under xampp/lampp/wampp.**

```
In php.ini file put your google email id and password also put email and password send mail file.

After complete this step go to gmail->setting
and do less secure option true  "[https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps]"
```

.

Comment: No i am not sending mail from localhost , this is live website

Comment: which server are you using.